# Datadog - When configuring a metric monitor, do i need to set a evaluation delay even if i require a full window data for evaluation?

Tags: datadog

I find datadog's documentation not clear about that, [it advices](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/configuration/?tab=thresholdalert#evaluation-delay) to delay Monitor's evaluation by `15min` when using cloud metrics (i'm using aws) but it also [says](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/types/metric/?tab=threshold#set-alert-conditions) that if i set Data Window to `require` the monitor will not be evaluated until the window is filled with data.

So i'm wondering if i need to set a evaluation delay even if i require a full window data for evaluation?

Comment: I think it would depend on what your evaluation timeframe is. If it's less than days, I'd probably go ahead and add the delay. But the best way to be sure is to try it both ways and see what happens.

Comment: In my personal example i'm using a 1min evaluation timeframe with a require full data window but no delay. Sometimes the evaluation shows an error but my monitor is not triggered, so i'm wondering how is it possible and if it has anything to do with the delay?